# Java create a new file, or, override the existing file

Tags: java, file

What I want to achieve is to create a file regardless of whether the file exists or not.

I tried using `File.createNewFile()` but that will only create the file if it does not already exists. Should I use `File.delete()` and then `File.createNewFile()`?

Or is there a clearer way of doing it?

Comment: What do you want to do with the file once you've created it?

Comment: Either leave it as an empty file or write some lines to it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

FileWriter has a constructor that takes 2 parameters too: The file name and a boolean. The boolean indicates whether to append or overwrite an existing file. Here are two Java FileWriter examples showing that:

```
Writer fileWriter = new FileWriter("c:\\data\\output.txt", true);  //appends to file

Writer fileWriter = new FileWriter("c:\\data\\output.txt", false); //overwrites file
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a suitable `Writer`:

```
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("abc.txt")));
br.write("some text");
```

It will create a file abc.txt if it doesn't exist. If it does, it will overwrite the file.

You can also open the file in append mode by using another constructor of FileWriter:

```
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("abc.txt"), true));
br.write("some text");
```

The documentation for above constructor says:

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second
>   argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file
>   rather than the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

**Java 7** introduced the `java.nio.file` package which includes the very useful `Files` class. This class provides the `write` method that does precisely what you're looking for. To save a file or overwrite an existing one, you can use the following command:

```java
Files.write(file, bytes);
```

Please note that the variable `path` here is of type `Path`. If you're using an instance of the `File` class, you may need to convert it to a `Path` using:

```java
Files.write(file.toPath(), bytes);
```

You can read more about this method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-):

> In other words, it opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist

Here's a test that demonstrates the method works as expected:

```java
@Test
void createsOrOverwrites(@TempDir final Path temp) throws IOException {
    final Path text = temp.resolve("hello.txt");
    Files.write(
        text,
        "Hello, world!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    );
    Assertions.assertTrue(Files.exists(text), "File should be created");
    Assertions.assertEquals(
        "Hello, world!",
        Files.readAllLines(text).get(0),
        "File should contain correct text"
    );
    Files.write(
        text,
        "I love StackOverflow!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    );
    Assertions.assertEquals(
        "I love StackOverflow!",
        Files.readAllLines(text).get(0),
        "File should be overwritten"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`File#createNewFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--) is safe, assuming the path is valid and you have write permissions on it. If a file already exists with that name, it will just return false:

```
File f = new File("myfile.txt");
if (f.createNewFile()) {
    // If there wasn't a file there beforehand, there is one now.
} else {
   // If there was, no harm, no foul
}

// And now you can use it.
```

Comment: I understood OP wanted to recreate the file from scratch if it exists, this would reuse the existing one.

Comment: The Question wants to *replace* any existing file. But `File#createNewFile` is documented as creating a new file “if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist”. So an existing file is left intact, not replaced.