# Create new file or delete and recreate if exist

Tags: java, io

I want to create a new file in src/main/resources with `FileOutputStream` or other.

I tried:

```
this.getClass().getResource("theFileIwantToCreate").getPath().getFile()
```

I have FileNotFoundExeption.

In my case I want to create or delete if exist and re create a new file in resource foder : src/main/resources.

thanks

Comment: You have to check first if the given file exist or not, before calling .getResource(). If it's present you can run this method or else you need to mkdir first.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html

Comment: how can i get the string path of resources folder ? (src/main/resources)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java create a new file, or, override the existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581404/java-create-a-new-file-or-override-the-existing-file)